# get_option error plugin development

Tags: plugins, options

Im creating a plugin with the following structure:

> ```
> plugins (folder)
> - myplugin (folder)
>  - myplugin_index.php (adminpanel file)
>  - myplugin_ajax.php (loading data when user enters a form on the "start page")
>
> themes (folder)
>  - mytheme (folder)
>   - template_my_own.php (this file have the form which calls the myplugin_ajax.php)
> ```

The plugin works just fine from the admin panel point of view. I have added data through the plugin from the admin panel.

But when I try to access data through the form in the file `template_my_own.php` I get the following error:

> ```
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function get_option() 
> in /var/www/example.com/wwwroot/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin_ajax.php 
> on line 14, referer: http://example.com/
> ```

I have tried the solutions from [both](http://blog.makingsense.com/2011/03/create-stand-alone-web-pages-or-widgets-that-use-wordpress-functions/) this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306612/using-wpdb-in-standalone-script/).

None of them work though. My code lookes like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Myplugin
Plugin URI: http://example.com
*/
?>
<?php
    $square = $_POST['square'];

    //Get arrays and remove empty array values
    $arrayFrom =            array_filter(get_option('from'), 'strlen');
    $arrayTo =          array_filter(get_option('to'), 'strlen');
    $arrayPrice =   array_filter(get_option('price'), 'strlen');


    //Sort arrays
    asort($arrayFrom);
    asort($arrayTo);
    asort($arrayPrice);


    //Go through values until we find the one
    foreach($arrayFrom as $index => $from)
    {
        if($from < $square && $arrayto[$index] > $square)
        {
            echo $from;
            echo '<br>TESTTESTTEST';
            echo $to;
        }
    }   
?>
```

How should I solve this and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

### How plugins loading works

WordPress has, as any other software, a specific order in which files get loaded. During loading WPs core files, there're specific points where you can either hook into `do_action()` or alter data during `apply_filters()` calls. Those functions always get called with a minimum of one argument: The name. Sometimes there're more arguments, which then are the callbacks.

Point is, that you have to wait until certain hooks to have some parts of the public API available.

### The rule...

Never ever just execute code without wrapping it into a function or method (the mentioned callback) which you then hook. For more information about the order in which those hooks appear, take a look [at the Codex and the Plugin API & Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Answer (score 1):

You should hook your function to the WordPress AJAX Api.

```
function your_ajax_function() {
    // your Script here
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_your_ajax_function', 'your_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_your_ajax_function', 'your_ajax_function' ); // Skip this line if you want the AJAX just for logged in users
```

Now you can easily call your function via Javascript:

```
var data =  {
    action: 'your_ajax_function',
    your_data: 'datatosubmit'
};
$.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
    // what to do with your response
});
```

Just be sure ajaxurl is defined. Usually it is `http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, but that depends on your WordPress setup.

If you use this method, you have all the WordPress functions available on your AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have WordPress loaded. Something along this lines:

`<?php include '../../../wp-load.php'; ?>`

but, this not advisable. I assume you want to do some ajax? If that's the case, do it like this outlined here: http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/